# Typing delay with remote.it SSH

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, remote-access

I started using Remote.It on my Windows 11 PC to connect to my Raspberry Pi via SSH even when I'm on a different Wi-Fi so that I can SSH into my Pi from anywhere.However I noticed that typing into the terminal was really slow and had a huge delay whenever I used Remote.It. At first I thought this was just because I was far away from the Pi, but even when I use Remote.It at home next to my Pi and I use my iPhone's hotspot for WiFi, the typing delay is super noticeable. Whenever I connect normally from the same network the typing speed is fine. Does anyone know how to fix this, or know a faster way to connect to my Pi via SSH from anywhere?

Comment: Can you check with a packet capture (or at least netstat/tcpview) to see whether your remote.it client is talking directly to your home IP address, or whether it's talking exclusively to cloud servers, and if so which country are those servers located in?

Comment: I just tried this using a VPN in Japan. It seems that the majority of the processes in TCPView had IP addresses in California near the SF Bay Area, which makes sense. This is probably where the servers are located and that may be what is causing the slow speed.